# Error al obtener mimeType de archivo jpg

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero subir una imagen jpg en laravel, pero según el archivo jpg que elijo, puedo subir correctamente la imagen o no

Este es el código de la vista

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('subir') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<label for="archivo"><b>Archivo: </b></label><br>
<input type="file" name="archivo" required>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Enviar" >
</form>
```

Estas son las rutas

```
Route::get('/examinar-imagen', 'PruebasController@examinarImagen')->name('examinar');
Route::post('/subir', 'PruebasController@subirImagen')->name('subir');
```

Este es el código del controlador

```
class PruebasController extends Controller
{
    
    public function examinarImagen()
    {
        return view('pruebas.examinar');
    }

    public function subirImagen(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->file('archivo'));
        die();
    
        //Recibimos el archivo y lo guardamos en la carpeta storage/app/public
        $request->file('archivo')->store('public');
        dd("subido y guardado");
    }
}
```

Con el var_dump() veo el archivo que estoy subiendo. Si elijo una imagen jpg cualquiera de mi ordenador puedo ver que el mimeType es 'image/jpeg' y se sube correctamente. El problema es cuando subo una imagen realizada con un móvil, entonces el mimeType devuelto es 'application/octet-stream' y ya la imagen no se sube

Os dejo una imagen original tomada con un móvil y con la que me falla por si podéis probar

https://mega.nz/file/0UNkgYCS#ZLIqIf0BRB62R_KuytwdZ4l5oLLEF4fIGolOVU16N_k

¿Por qué la imagen jpg realizada con el móvil no tiene un mimeType image/jpeg?

Gracias!

Comment: `application/octet-stream` suele significar que el archivo se ha subido sin extensión

Comment: Normalmente las fotos tomadas con celular suelen pesar más MB, verificaste que tu `php.ini` acepte subidas de más de 4.7 MB?

Comment: Sí, post_max_size = 8M, también he probado con fotos de 2 y 3 megas y siempre da el mismo error y todos los archivos tienen extensión .jpg, sólo me pasa con fotos tomadas con el móvil y de distintos móviles

Comment: Revisa si algo de este post te ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st

Comment: Ya lo estuve revisando pero no veo la solución :(

Comment: Revisa tambien la variable de php.ini `upload_max_filesize` que generalmente esta en 2M (en conjunto con post_max_size hacen el tamaño maximo efectivo de upload).

Comment: Ahorá sí, con la variable upload_max_filesize = 8M ya me reconoce el mimeType y puedo subir la imagen sin problemas. Gracias!